# iOS Calculating the vertical movement distance of the device

Tags: ios, xcode, distance

I'm looking to create a function for my app which records the distance travelled in the vertical plane. More specifically, I want to record how far the device has been 'dropped' - this could mean dropped at arm's length onto the floor or dropped slowly with the user as they go down ten floors in an elevator. I'm looking for advice on the best way to calculate this with a relatively high level of accuracy.

I've read a little on the difficulty in accurately measuring distance travelled using core motion - especially as I need it to work even if the device rotates during the movement. From what I've researched it seems as though it would be impossible, or at least very difficult, to achieve this using core motion.

Would I be able to achieve this effect with Core Location instead? I've seen posts about calculating lateral distance, as in during a car journey, but nothing about vertical distance.

Is it as simple as 'startingAltitude - endingAltitude = distanceTravelled?

If so - how accurate is the altitude measurement of Core Location and how could I get started with this behaviour? I'm fairly new to iOS programming and would appreciate any pointers on the most appropriate method of achieving the function I want.

Thanks

Comment: What is accurate for you? one meter? one kilometer? The accuracy depends on the location or your phone reception. Generally speaking this is not an easy task. To help you more we need more informations.

Comment: Accuracy for me is more like nearest half-meter. Or better. From trawling the web I'm starting to think this may not be possible.. but any help is still appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are serious limitations to both approaches.

Using an accelerometer to measure distance travelled requires very precise and accurate real-time measurement of acceleration. Any error in acceleration reading leads to error in your velocity calculation, which makes your location reading drift from the real location. Drift gets worse over time, to the point where the error swamps the actual location reading.

Based on my testing the altitude reading in iOS GPS devices is really bad. +/- 100 or more meters is not uncommon. Indoors GPS readings tend to get really bad, and the altitude reading is bad enough to start.

Comment: Thanks. I think this confirms my suspicions - guess I'm gonna have to throw this function out the window as it seems the device technology isn't good enough. Oh well!